# Google Font not Rendering properly on Webview in Javafx When Loading Google Form

Tags: javafx, webview, google-forms

I want to load a Google form in my application so that user can submit bug report. I am using WebView to load that page. It's loading, but text are not showing. Instead of showing text, it is showing box. But on browser it is showing perfectly. Here is the screenshot of that page.

[Google form page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxBA2.png)

Here is my code snippet:

```
    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.getEngine().load(googleFormURL);
    mainLayout.setCenter(webView);
```

But if I sign in there, it show properly, no font problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround: Instead of using the new Google Forms use the old Google Forms.

Note: The old Google Forms theme feature allow to customize several settings like the font to be used for several elements.

From https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888?hl=en

> Opt out of the new Forms
>
> If you need to, you can go back to the Forms. In the bottom left
>   corner, click Exit [image: Exit].
>
> You can only opt out of the new Forms on a computer.

Comment: Sorry, still facing problem.